# QToolBar item margin

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar

I have added several items to the QToolBar using addAction method. Is there a way to control  a spacing inside item? I mean spacing between item text (or icon) and item border[image]

Comment: You could try [`QWidget::setContentsMargins`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins).

Comment: @G.M. QWidget::contentMargins doesn't affect spacing inside QToolBar's item

Answer (score 4):

You can use style sheets. Example:

```
myToolbar->setStyleSheet("QToolButton { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 40px; }");
```

See [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) and [Customizing QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton)

Comment: This works only to increase padding - if I set padding-left: 40px the spacing really grows up. But if I set padding-left: 0px nothing changes - it seems that there is something like minimum padding level.

Comment: It seems that you can decrease the space setting a negative padding (I've tried with Qt 5.5, Windows style (Win 10))